# Angular Material Expansion panel with sub expansion panels

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-material-5

Actually i have used angular material expansion panel (accordian) for panel expansions. So what i have tried is i just want to display child panels inside one parent expansion panel something like this. See picture below.

[image]

Databases is going to be the top level parent panel and inside of it i have different databases as child panels. For that i have written the code like this. But the code is not working means when i click on any parent panel inside child panel then everything gets collapsed. I mean to say the panels are collapsing.
See code below:

```
<mat-accordion>

        <mat-expansion-panel>
            <mat-expansion-panel-header>
              <mat-panel-title>
                Databases
              </mat-panel-title>
              </mat-expansion-panel-header>


              <mat-expansion-panel (opened)="panelOpenState = true"
                             (closed)="panelOpenState = false">
                  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                    <mat-panel-title>
                      MySQL
                    </mat-panel-title>
                  </mat-expansion-panel-header>

                  <mat-form-field>
                    <textarea matInput placeholder="Assertions"></textarea>
                  </mat-form-field>

                  <mat-form-field>
                      <textarea matInput placeholder="Assertions"></textarea>
                    </mat-form-field>

                    <mat-form-field>
                        <textarea matInput placeholder="Assertions"></textarea>
                      </mat-form-field>

                      <mat-form-field>
                          <textarea matInput placeholder="Assertions"></textarea>
                        </mat-form-field>
                </mat-expansion-panel>


                <mat-expansion-panel (opened)="panelOpenState = true"
                             (closed)="panelOpenState = false">
                  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                    <mat-panel-title>
                        Oracle
                    </mat-panel-title>
                  </mat-expansion-panel-header>

                  <mat-form-field>
                    <textarea matInput placeholder="Assertions"></textarea>
                  </mat-form-field>

                  <mat-form-field>
                      <textarea matInput placeholder="Assertions"></textarea>
                    </mat-form-field>

                    <mat-form-field>
                        <textarea matInput placeholder="Assertions"></textarea>
                      </mat-form-field>

                      <mat-form-field>
                          <textarea matInput placeholder="Assertions"></textarea>
                        </mat-form-field>
                </mat-expansion-panel>

                <mat-expansion-panel (opened)="panelOpenState = true"
                             (closed)="panelOpenState = false">
                  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                    <mat-panel-title>
                        Postgres
                    </mat-panel-title>
                  </mat-expansion-panel-header>

                  <mat-form-field>
                    <textarea matInput placeholder="Assertions"></textarea>
                  </mat-form-field>

                  <mat-form-field>
                      <textarea matInput placeholder="Assertions"></textarea>
                    </mat-form-field>

                    <mat-form-field>
                        <textarea matInput placeholder="Assertions"></textarea>
                      </mat-form-field>

                      <mat-form-field>
                          <textarea matInput placeholder="Assertions"></textarea>
                        </mat-form-field>
                </mat-expansion-panel>

                <mat-expansion-panel (opened)="panelOpenState = true"
                             (closed)="panelOpenState = false">
                  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                    <mat-panel-title>
                        SQLServer
                    </mat-panel-title>
                  </mat-expansion-panel-header>

                  <mat-form-field>
                    <textarea matInput placeholder="Assertions"></textarea>
                  </mat-form-field>

                  <mat-form-field>
                      <textarea matInput placeholder="Assertions"></textarea>
                    </mat-form-field>

                    <mat-form-field>
                        <textarea matInput placeholder="Assertions"></textarea>
                      </mat-form-field>

                      <mat-form-field>
                          <textarea matInput placeholder="Assertions"></textarea>
                        </mat-form-field>
                </mat-expansion-panel>

                <mat-expansion-panel (opened)="panelOpenState = true"
                             (closed)="panelOpenState = false">
                  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                    <mat-panel-title>
                        MongoDB
                    </mat-panel-title>
                  </mat-expansion-panel-header>

                  <mat-form-field>
                    <textarea matInput placeholder="Assertions"></textarea>
                  </mat-form-field>

                  <mat-form-field>
                      <textarea matInput placeholder="Assertions"></textarea>
                    </mat-form-field>

                    <mat-form-field>
                        <textarea matInput placeholder="Assertions"></textarea>
                      </mat-form-field>

                      <mat-form-field>
                          <textarea matInput placeholder="Assertions"></textarea>
                        </mat-form-field>
                </mat-expansion-panel>

          </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

My plan is to display only that particular panel only. This is very strange its not working for me. If i place expansion panels in seperate panels then working for me. Can anybody suggest me?

Answer (score 5):

As of today, you can. [**see this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-95u99z)

```
 <!-- level 01 -->
  <mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel
      (opened)="panelOpenState = true"
      (closed)="panelOpenState = false"
    >
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>Week 01</mat-panel-title>
        <mat-panel-description>1 entry</mat-panel-description>
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-accordion>
        <mat-expansion-panel
          (opened)="panelOpenState = true"
          (closed)="panelOpenState = false"
        >
          <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title>Day 01</mat-panel-title>
            <mat-panel-description>Temperature warning</mat-panel-description>
          </mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <p>On day #1 of the 1nd week an alarm was raised</p>
        </mat-expansion-panel>
      </mat-accordion>
    </mat-expansion-panel>

    <mat-expansion-panel>
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>Week 02</mat-panel-title>
        <mat-panel-description>2 entries</mat-panel-description>
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>

      <!-- level 02 -->
      <mat-accordion>
        <mat-expansion-panel
          (opened)="panelOpenState = true"
          (closed)="panelOpenState = false"
        >
          <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title>Day 01</mat-panel-title>
            <mat-panel-description>Production success</mat-panel-description>
          </mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <p>On day #1 of the 2nd week The production was successful!</p>
        </mat-expansion-panel>

        <mat-expansion-panel>
          <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title>Day 02</mat-panel-title>
            <mat-panel-description>2 entries</mat-panel-description>
          </mat-expansion-panel-header>

          <!-- level 03 -->
          <mat-accordion>
            <mat-expansion-panel
              (opened)="panelOpenState = true"
              (closed)="panelOpenState = false"
            >
              <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                <mat-panel-title>03:00</mat-panel-title>
                <mat-panel-description>Alarm</mat-panel-description>
              </mat-expansion-panel-header>
              <p>On day two at 3am was an alarm</p>
            </mat-expansion-panel>

            <mat-expansion-panel>
              <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                <mat-panel-title>10:00</mat-panel-title>
                <mat-panel-description>Info</mat-panel-description>
              </mat-expansion-panel-header>
              <p>Delievery was successfull</p>
            </mat-expansion-panel>
          </mat-accordion>
        </mat-expansion-panel>
      </mat-accordion>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
  </mat-accordion>
```

Comment: This is great. is there a way to make multiple columns?

Answer (score 5):

You can first have a mat-accordian, then one mat-expansion-panel "Databases" and then another div inside that mat-expansion panel. This div contains multiple mat-expansion panels such as "MySql" , "Oracle" etc.

Here:

```
<mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel>
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
         <mat-panel-title>
            Databases
         </mat-panel-title>
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <div>
       <mat-expansion-panel>
          <mat-expansion-panel-header>
              <mat-panel-title>
            MySQL
              </mat-panel-title>
          </mat-expansion-panel-header>
       </mat-expansion-panel>
       <mat-expansion-panel>
          <mat-expansion-panel-header>
              <mat-panel-title>
            Oracle
              </mat-panel-title>
          </mat-expansion-panel-header>
       </mat-expansion-panel>
      </div>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

Answer (score 1):

mat-expansion-panel [does not currently support nesting](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/9921).
You should probably use [mat-tree](https://material.angular.io/components/tree/overview#nested-tree) instead.